# Migration Path for Content Database from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Subscription Edition

Tags: upgrade-sharepoint

FYI.  Based on the documentation, the migration path from SharePoint (SP) 2013 to SP Subscription Edition (SE) is to go to SP 2016 and then you can go to SP SE.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/overview-of-the-upgrade-process-subscription-edition

However, I discovered something very interesting by accident.   I was practicing the migration in a development environment and for one of my content databases, I forgot to do the SP2016 upgrade.  I was able to run mount-spcontentdatabase on a SP2013 content database and it upgraded successfully.

I didn't notice any major issues after doing so.

If SP SE didn't have the migration code to upgrade the SP 2013 content database, I would think that the Mount-SPContentDatabase powershell would display an error indicating the schema version is too old. It appears that SP SE has the migration code to upgrade from SP2013 content dbs (upgraded to recent SharePoint CU versions).

1. Has anyone else tried migrating a content database directly from SP2013 to SP SE?
2. Any recommendations on whether we should or should not take the shortcut of migrating the content database directly from SP2013 to SP SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reasons I should take the extra time upgrading the content db to SP2016 before migrating to SP SE?

Supportability from Microsoft when something goes wrong.

Comment: That's the obvious answer.  Modified the question slightly to see if anyone else has tried the direct upgrade approach.  I am going to ask Microsoft directly, as well.   For production, I'll likely take the extra time do go to SP2016 first unless Microsoft changes the documentation indicating the SP2013 to SP SE path is supported.

Comment: The PG has been firm on N-2 for upgrades since the pre-betas of SPSE.